# How do I add some JavaScript at the bottom of every layout using a pipeline?

Tags: pipelines, javascript

I'm wanting to add some JavaScript to the bottom of every page, but I don't want to add it to the layout(s), so I'd like a way of doing it with a pipeline (or similar).

I've tried a few of the MVC pipelines, and within there I've used Sitecore.Context.ClientPage.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock().  The code runs with no errors, but the page never has the script added.  Perhaps it's a timing thing with the order of the pipelines, I don't know.

Has anyone had any luck with doing this sort of thing before?  How can it be done?

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but just as a comment... I've seen similar approaches before and it is really hard to debug. Front-end issues that the front-end team can't find because it's buried in a pipeline in the server-side code makes fixing bugs a pain. I usually recommend keeping your presentation stuff as much in the presentation layer as possible.

Comment: Why you don't want to / can't include javascript to layout? I am with @JayS. This shouldn't be hard-coded in the code behind. It should be part of footer component or another rendering that will be placed in footer

Answer (score 1):

### Short answer:

- Yes, it can be done via **mvc.getPageRendering** with some additional processors.
- But where is the code? It's from [Habitat at github](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat)

### The detail is:

Habitat has implemented this requirement, you can take a view of [Assets module in Foundation layer](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/tree/master/src/Foundation/Assets/code)

#### Configure Pipeline's processors

1. They added a couple of additional processors into **mvc.getPageRendering** pipeline through [Foundation.Assets.config](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Foundation/Assets/code/App_Config/Include/Foundation/Foundation.Assets.config), e.g. ClearAssets, AddAssets and so on
2. The implementation of a processor, for example, [AddAssets.cs](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Foundation/Assets/code/Pipelines/GetPageRendering/AddAssets.cs)
3. Then, they leave the task of storing assets for [AssetRepository.cs](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Foundation/Assets/code/Repositories/AssetRepository.cs)
4. Eventually, [RenderAssetsService.cs](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Foundation/Assets/code/Services/RenderAssetsService.cs) is responsible for rendering assets to the view.

#### How to use

1. From the module which will be using Foundation.Assets, such as Foundation.Theming (from Habitat), take a look at [Foundation.Theming.config](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Foundation/Theming/code/App_Config/Include/Foundation/Foundation.Theming.config), in which they declare the assets which should be rendered when needed.

   - Assets can be javascript or css which will be files or inline (I have not tried with this).
     [image]
   - It's also configured to be rendered for specific or all sites (if you're in multi-sites scenario), because it has been handled in [RenderAssetsService.cs](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Foundation/Assets/code/Services/RenderAssetsService.cs)
     [image]
2. To render, let get [Default.cshtml](https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat/blob/master/src/Project/Habitat/code/Views/Website/Layouts/Default.cshtml) from Project/Habitat as our example

   - They can be rendered at Head or Bottom through the lines of code
     [image]

Hope it's useful